# How to define serialization for custom type used as value for custom Django field

Tags: django, django-reversion

I have made my own custom models.TextField subclass, which takes classes as its values and encodes those values as the CODE attribute of the given class in the database. All of this is so far working, but I want to use Django-reversion, which serializes models and saves the model in a version table every time a change is made. I'm using this for auditing purposes on my application.

Reversion can't serialize the values that I am assigning to my custom field, claiming that they are not serializable. How do I go about defining a serialization method for my objects? I can't just define a DjangoJSONEncoder subclass (the class that Django is using to serialize by default), because I don't have control over the code that is calling its serialize method because it's part of Django-reversion. This is the stack trace, which eventually fails at Python's default json encoder:

```
ERROR: Could not save initial version for AccessCircuitRTTicket 3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/management/commands/createinitialrevisions.py", line 87, in handle
    self.create_initial_revisions(app, model_class, comment, batch_size, verbosity)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/management/commands/createinitialrevisions.py", line 123, in create_initial_revisions
    default_revision_manager.save_revision((obj,), comment=comment)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 430, in save_revision
    for obj in objects
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 430, in <genexpr>
    for obj in objects
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 108, in get_version_data
    "serialized_data": self.get_serialized_data(obj),
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/revisions.py", line 91, in get_serialized_data
    fields = list(self.get_fields_to_serialize()),
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 122, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 58, in serialize
    self.end_object(obj)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 52, in end_object
    cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.json_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 181, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 427, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 401, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 401, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 435, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/home/sgalbraith/.python_virtualenvs/unleash/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 104, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 177, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <class 'console.broadband.enumerations.ProvisioningTicket'> is not JSON serializable
```

There's a vague suggestion toward the answer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/serialization/#id2) in the definition of LazyEncoder and the text immediately preceding it.

Answer (score 2):

After a day of struggling I've come up with an answer. I'm not particularly happy with it, as it puts the responsibility far away from the type that I want to serialize. A better answer would be nice! Here's what I got...

Note that the Django custom field that I have has values which are classes (i.e. they have a type of type) and are subclasses of EnumMember, having a class member called CODE which gives their string representation.

I created the following module *crm.serializers.json* and set the SERIALIZATION_MODULES in the settings to

```
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {
    'json': 'crm.serializers.json',
}
```

The crm.serializers.json code follows:

```
# Avoid shadowing the standard library json module
from __future__ import absolute_import

from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder, Serializer, \
    Deserializer as DjangoDeserializer
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

from crm.enum import EnumMember
import json

####################################################################################################
#
#    Extension of Django serialization capability so that apps such as Django-reversion can deal
#    with custom fields.
#
####################################################################################################
class Serializer(Serializer):

    # Override
    # This is a copy paste of the superclass method, but with cls=ExtendedJSONEncoder
    # instead of cls=DjangoJSONEncoder below
    def end_object(self, obj):
        # self._current has the field data
        indent = self.options.get("indent")
        if not self.first:
            self.stream.write(",")
            if not indent:
                self.stream.write(" ")
        if indent:
            self.stream.write("\n")
        json.dump(self.get_dump_object(obj), self.stream,
                  cls=ExtendedJSONEncoder, **self.json_kwargs)
        self._current = None
        pass


Deserializer = DjangoDeserializer


class ExtendedJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    """
    Provides default serialization for custom data types as well as default ones.
    """
    def default(self, obj):
        if type(obj) == type and issubclass(obj, EnumMember):
            return obj.CODE
        else:
            return super(ExtendedJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure because I don't see your TextField subclass but
`value_to_string(self, obj)`
is used in serialization framework and you could override this method of Field class.

like this

```py
def value_to_string(self, obj):
    return self.value_from_object(obj.CODE)
```

For deserialization make sure that your `to_python(self, value)` works right

Comment: I know it's old news but I had the same problem and this question came up.